# Singleton Class not working into multiple files

Tags: c++, file, oop, singleton

Say I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Something
{
    int field1;

    static Something *nill;
    static bool initialized;

    static void initialize() {
        if (initialized)
            return;
        initialized = true;
    }

public:
    static Something* Nill()
    {
        initialize();
        return nill;
    }

    static Something* Singleton(int field1)
    {
        initialize();
        Something *ret = new Something();
        ret->field1 = field1;

        return ret;
    }
}

Something* Something::nill = new Something();
bool Something::initialized = false;

int main(void)
{
    Something *smth = something->Nill();
    return 0;
}
```

Why isn't 'Something' a Singleton Class, and how  could I make it one? Also how could I split this code into 2 files a .h and a .cpp? I had problems with that because I have some global variables here and I don't know how to use them in other files..

Comment: *"when I instantiate the new "root1" is that at the end when I dump the fields to have the exact same fields"* - this clearly is not part of the attached code. `initialize` doesn't perform any initialization actions while `Singleton` is not used at all.

Comment: @user7860670 Yeah, you're right, sorry

Comment: Take a look at `static Something* Singleton(int field1)`. It will return a new instance every time you call it. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @churill Hello.. hmm I think I need a new instance there because I am constructing some kind of tree and i will need I guess new instances

Comment: @J.Homer Then it's not a singleton anymore. Maybe you need to split this in two classes? Also creating a new instance and initializaing private members is usually the job of a constructor.

Comment: @churill Hm.. okay, I thought there would be some way to create a singleton tree

Comment: I would go for a (reusable) tree class and a singleton class that holds an instance of this tree-class to make it globally available. For the correct implmentation of the "Construct on first use"-idiom see [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use). But always keep in mind that singletons should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a singleton class. Singleton class implies that in any given time you cannot have more than 1 instance of the class. In your example, you're not only creating a new instance but even return new class objects in its methods.

Make a default constructor protected (copy or move constructors too if you really want to be sure it's as singleton). Then use your static 'nill' as shown below:

```
class Something {
protected:
  Something() = default;
...

int main() {
  Something::nill->Nill();
...
```

P.s. Are you sure you need a singleton? Your methods say opposite.